# Are there any RandomForest Regression implementation libraries for Java/CPP apart from Smile, Spark and Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

I would like to know if there are any Java/CPP libraries with RandomForest Implementation. It would be better if the library is Apache licensed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is to solve problems in your code, not for recommending tools and libraries.

Comment: There's one java implementation at https://github.com/DronovIlya/random-forest-java

Comment: [JSAT](https://github.com/EdwardRaff/JSAT) has an implementation of [RandomForest](https://github.com/EdwardRaff/JSAT/blob/master/JSAT/src/jsat/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.java). But also GPLv3 licensed.

Comment: The ones mentioned  JSAT and Dronovilya are having just RandomForest classifiers. Is there any library where I can find an implementation for RandomForest Regression?